# mysql connection function pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php

require_once "includes/db_data_inc.php";

try 
{
    /* In this way I get a db connection handle */
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;port=8889;dbname=$db_name",$db_user,$db_pass);

}
catch (PDOException $pdoe) 
{
    error_log($pdoe->getMessage());
    die("Failed to connect to the database.");
}

$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,false);

try
{
    $success_msg = NULL;
    $unsucess_msg = NULL;

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name,surname,address,birth_place,province,birthdate,sex,treatment) VALUES (?)";
    $SHT = $DBH->prepare($query);

    $SHT->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
    $SHT->bindParam(2, $_POST['surname']);
    $SHT->bindParam(3, $_POST['address']);
    $SHT->bindParam(4, $_POST['birth_place']);
    $SHT->bindParam(5, $_POST['province']);
    $SHT->bindParam(6, $_POST['dt']);
    $SHT->bindParam(7, $_POST['gender']);
    $SHT->bindParam(8, $_POST['select']);

    $DBH->beginTransaction();

    if($SHT->execute())
    {
        $DBH->commit();
        $success_msg = "The emergency call was correctly sent...";
    }
    else
    {
        $unsucess_msg = "It couldn't estabilished a connection to call center...";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $pdoe)
{
    $DBH->rollBack();
}


/* Close the db connection */
$DBH = null;
```

?>

here it is my mysql connection function to connect to mysql db and an insert query. The code doesn't work.There is maybe some error?Because I don't receive any error from php console but I don't even see any result in the page.any idea?

I worked on the console and obtained this error:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

what does it mean?

Comment: Use something like `var_dump($pdoe);` to get the exception. Is somehow useless to just rollback the transaction and completely ignoring the actual error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One '?' just doesn't match with the eight parameters you pass in later.

Take a look at the examples of the [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method.

Use something like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name,surname,address,birth_place,province,birthdate,sex,treatment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: So I have put eight '?' inline...?

Comment: or I can create placeholder like: bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']) and substitue :name to '?'. Right?

Comment: @eng_mazzy: Just look at the examples in my link, the should answer all your questions.